# Display multiple results with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join, inner-join

I have these three MySQL tables:

```
companies                    services                      auxiliary
id_company name_company      id_service  name_service      id_company id_service   

1          Google            1           Search            1          1   
2          Yahoo             2           Calendar          1          2  
                             3           Mail              1          3
                             4           Maps              1          4
                                                           2          1
                                                           2          3
```

I am wondering if I could display with only one query (I'm using php):

```
Google: Search, Calendar, Mail, Maps.
Yahoo: Search, Mail.
```

Now what I am doing is display the companies, and for each company I make another MySQL query to display the services. Is it possible to do that with only one query?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is:  "Yes".

Oh, you want to know how to do it as well.  The key is to join the tables together and then aggregate at the company level.  I am going to assume that you really want the output as two columns (company name, services), rather than one string with them concatenated together.

The SQL is:

```
select c.name_company, group_concat(s.name_service separator ', ') as services
from auxiliary a join
     companies c
     on a.id_company = c.id_company join
     services s
     on a.id_service =  s.id_service
group by c.id_company, c.name_company;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could. Although in my opinion the approach you described seems more natural to me.
(Having one query/cursor for the companies, and another one for the services)

You could use one single query to prepare following list:
Google, Search
Google, Calendar
Google, Mail
Google, Maps
Yahoo, Search
Yahoo, Mail
...
(I have left out the ids for simplicity)
Then you run through the list, every time the company *changes* you begin a new result line. I find this a bit more complicated than the approach you described.

Comment: Yes, it could be a good solution, but I simplified the example, so I couldn't use it exactly you propose! Thank you :)